# Название улицы Цементная слободка

Tags: untagged

Есть в Керчи улица Цементная слободка. Стоит ли писать Слободка с прописной?

Answer (score 2):

С прописной буквы не будут писаться только родовые слова, служебные слова, а также такие слова как *имени*, *лет* или *года*.

Чтобы определить, является ли *слободка* родовым словом, можно обратиться к Государственному Адресному Реестру (посмотреть можно, например, через [ФИАС](https://fias.nalog.ru/)). В нем данный элемент улично-дорожной сети зарегистрирован именно как *улица*.

Поэтому *слободка* пишется с прописной:

*улица Цементная Слободка*.

Замечу, что возможно написание *Цементная слободка*, если речь идет об историческом поселении, или если вы используете народное название непосредственных окрестностей улицы.